# Insert into another table

Tags: mysql

i create a User Group script for my site and i have a query that creates groups with an id (AUTO_INCREMENT on)

My query that insert the Group Information to wss_usergroups look like

```
if ($setting['email_on'] == 0) {
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wss_usergroups (groupname, url, password, date)
VALUES('$groupname', '$seo_url', '$passwordpro', '$date')") or die (mysql_error());
```

i try to add the name from the usergroup into the wss_users table or the id from the first query that would be created, here a example

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wss_usergroups (groupname, url, password, date)
VALUES('$groupname', '$seo_url', '$passwordpro', '$date')") or die (mysql_error());

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wss_users (group)
VALUES('$groupname')") or die (mysql_error());
```

but that not works, can you help me what im doing wrong?
I think i need to add what row be selected in wss_users and where he inserts the data

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `pdo`. Also, you're not escaping your variables: [sql injection.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: yes this( here was a MySql error when adding the group: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) VALUES ('Group')' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**date** is mysql reserved words so you can't direct use them .Wrap it with ``` backtrics (``) ```

```
INSERT INTO wss_usergroups (`groupname`, `url`, `password`, `date`)
VALUES('$groupname',
       '$seo_url',
       '$passwordpro',
       '$date')
```

also GROUP is same

```
INSERT INTO wss_users (`group`)
VALUES('$groupname')
```

[**SEE MYSQL RESERVED WORDS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Date isn't, see the table on the link you post ;)

Answer (score 0):

Group is a mysql-keyword, use backticks so mysql knows you mean the column-name:

```
"INSERT INTO wss_users (`group`) VALUES('$groupname')"
```

For a full list of reserved words see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thank you now it works, but he insert the value into a new row at the end, i can search in net but maybe you can tell me how he insert it into the table which user created the group this is the $_COOKIE['wss_user'] i think i need to add it with WHERE or?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean that you want to add the group name to an existing user? Use an update-query: `UPDATE wss_users SET `group` = '$group_name' WHERE username = 'clayman'`

Comment: Also, if your writing new code: switch to mysqli as the mysql_*-functions are deprecated. See http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php - and make sure you properly escape your data with mysqli_real_escape_string().

Comment: Yes the user who is logged in can see a formular and when he send the forumular he creates a new usergroup in wss_usergroups but i need to set it to groupadmin thats why i need to enter the groupname in his row wss_users. i try this way ("INSERT INTO wss_users WHERE name = '$_COOKIE['wss_ref']' (`group`) , i dont know is maybe the id from the first table to insert it into his user information would be better? eh and my code dont works i dont know why

Comment: That query is invalid. `INSERT INTO` creates a new row, `UPDATE` updates an existing row. So if you want to update an existing user-row, use an `UPDATE`-query, not an `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: ok thank you but i cant write WHERE id = '$_COOKIE['wss_userid']'

Comment: my code looks now $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE wss_users SET groupadmin = '$group_name' WHERE id='$_COOKIE[userid]'")or die (mysql_error());  and no errors but he dont update the table

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE wss_users SET groupadmin='$groupname' WHERE id='$id'") or die (mysql_error()); thats is the workin query thank you for your help